# Perform Per metric data retention policy in prometheus

Tags: prometheus

Does prometheus has a method of "reducing" old data like for example influxdb has ?
For example i want to store some requests counter with resolution of "sample every 1 minute" for last week, then reduce and store sample per 10 minutes for last month and then remove the data completely.